# Username and Password Authentication for WCF Hosted in Azure

Tags: wcf, azure

I would like to use the Authorization in WCF Hosted in Azure. At this stage I'm thinking of using username and password using asp membership provider.

Are there any better options available in Azure for Authentication?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

although you can use the asp membership provider, there are other options you might want to consider. First, if you go for the aspnet membership provider and you use sql azure you'll need to run a different set of scripts, explained here:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2006191

next you could aslo use the Access Control Service to secure your service in a 'truly' azure fashion. please take a look at

http://www.microsoft.com/windowsazure/appfabric/ and then access control..

Kr.
Didier